# How to force missing join in SQL?

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I need to left outer join two tables, but I also always want to have "non-matched" row. Example:

```
left table:

|--------------|
| *c1* | *key* |
|--------------|
| a1   | a     |
|------|-------|
| b1   | b     |
|--------------|
```

```
right table:

|--------------|
| *c2* | *key* |
|--------------|
| a2   | a     |
|--------------|
```

```
expected result, joined by *key* column:

|-------------|
| *c1* | *c2* | 
|-------------|
| a1   | a2   |
|------|------|
| a1   | null | <- this row is needed
|------|------|
| b1   | null | <- in case there is no match, only one "value, null" row is needed
|-------------|
```

What's the best way to achieve it? Preferably without using `distinct` or `union`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an `inner join` and `union all`:

```
select l.c1, r.c2
from left l join
     right r
     on l.key = r.key
union all
select l.c1, null
from left l;
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot, Gordon.